# How to format a floating number to maximum fixed width in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers, number-formatting

I am writing an input file to a program with roots in the 60s, and it reads data from fixed-width data fields on text files. The format is:

- field width 8 characters
- floating point numbers must contain a `'.'` or be written on exponential format, e.g. `'1.23e8'`

The closest i've gotten is

```
print "{0:8.3g}".format(number)
```

which yields `'1.23e+06'` with `1234567`, and `'    1234'` with `1234`.

I would like to tweak this however, to get

- `'1234567.'` with `1234567` (i.e. not going to exponential format before it is
  required),
- `'   1234.'` with `1234` (i.e. ending with a dot so it is not interpreted as an integer),
- `'1.235e+7'` with `12345678` (i.e. using only one digit for the exponent),
- `'-1.23e+7'` with `-1234567` (i.e. not violating the 8 digit maximum on
  negative numbers).

Since this is (as far as I recall) easily achievable with Fortran and the problem probably comes up now and then when interacting with legacy code I suspect that there must be some easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I simply took the answer by @Harvey251 but split into test part and the part we need in production.

Usage would be:

```
# save the code at the end as formatfloat.py and then
import formatfloat

# do this first
width = 8
ff8 = formatfloat.FormatFloat(width)

# now use ff8 whenever you need
print(ff8(12345678901234))
```

And here is the solution.  Save the code as formatfloat.py and import it to use FlotFormat class.  As I said below, loop part of calculation better be moved to init part of the FormatFlot class.

```
import unittest

class FormatFloat:
    def __init__(self, width = 8):
        self.width = width
        self.maxnum = int('9'*(width - 1))  # 9999999
        self.minnum = -int('9'*(width - 2)) # -999999

    def __call__(self, x):

        # for small numbers
        # if -999,999 < given < 9,999,999:
        if x > self.minnum and x < self.maxnum:

            # o = f'{x:7}'
            o = f'{x:{self.width - 1}}'

            # converting int to float without adding zero
            if '.' not in o:
                o += '.'

            # float longer than 8 will need rounding to fit width
            elif len(o) > self.width:
                # output = str(round(x, 7 - str(x).index(".")))
                o = str(round(x, self.width-1 - str(x).index('.')))

        else:

            # for exponents
            # added a loop for super large numbers or negative as "-" is another char
            # Added max(max_char, 5) to account for max length of less 
            #     than 5, was having too much fun
            # TODO can i come up with a threshold value for these up front, 
            #     so that i dont have to do this calc for every value??
            for n in range(max(self.width, 5) - 5, 0, -1):
                fill = f'.{n}e'
                o = f'{x:{fill}}'.replace('+0', '+')

                # if all good stop looping
                if len(o) == self.width:
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Number is too large to fit in {self.width} characters", x)
        return o


class TestFormatFloat(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_all(self):
        test = ( 
            ("1234567.", 1234567), 
            ("-123456.", -123456), 
            ("1.23e+13", 12345678901234), 
            ("123.4567", 123.4567), 
            ("123.4568", 123.45678), 
            ("1.234568", 1.2345678), 
            ("0.123457", 0.12345678), 
            ("   1234.", 1234), 
            ("1.235e+7", 12345678), 
            ("-1.23e+6", -1234567),
            )

        width = 8
        ff8 = FormatFloat(width)

        for expected, given in test:
            output = ff8(given)
            self.assertEqual(len(output), width, msg=output)
            self.assertEqual(output, expected, msg=given)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made a slight addition to yosukesabai's contribution to account for the rare case where rounding will make the width of the string 7 characters instead of 8!

```
class FormatFloat:
def __init__(self, width = 8):
    self.width = width
    self.maxnum = int('9'*(width - 1))  # 9999999
    self.minnum = -int('9'*(width - 2)) # -999999

def __call__(self, x):

    # for small numbers
    # if -999,999 < given < 9,999,999:
    if x > self.minnum and x < self.maxnum:

        # o = f'{x:7}'
        o = f'{x:{self.width - 1}}'

        # converting int to float without adding zero
        if '.' not in o:
            o += '.'

        # float longer than 8 will need rounding to fit width
        elif len(o) > self.width:
            # output = str(round(x, 7 - str(x).index(".")))
            o = str(round(x, self.width - 1 - str(x).index('.')))
            if len(o) < self.width:
                o+=(self.width-len(o))*'0'

    else:

        # for exponents
        # added a loop for super large numbers or negative as "-" is another char
        # Added max(max_char, 5) to account for max length of less 
        #     than 5, was having too much fun
        # TODO can i come up with a threshold value for these up front, 
        #     so that i dont have to do this calc for every value??
        for n in range(max(self.width, 5) - 5, 0, -1):
            fill = f'.{n}e'
            o = f'{x:{fill}}'.replace('+0', '+')

            # if all good stop looping
            if len(o) == self.width:
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Number is too large to fit in {self.width} characters", x)
    return o
```

Answer (score 1):

You've clearly gotten very close, but I think your final solution is going to involve writing a custom formatter. For example, I don't believe the [mini-formatting language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) can control the width of the exponent like you want.

(BTW, in your first example you don't have a "+" after the "e" but in the others you do. Making it clear which one you want might help other answerers.)

If I were writing this formatting function, the first thing I would do is write a thorough set of tests for it. Either [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) or [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) would be suitable.

Then you work on your formatting function until all those tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like, admittedly it's a little late and I spent way too long on it, but I came upon this when trying to figure out something similar.

```
import unittest


class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_all(self):
        test = (
            ("1234567.", 1234567),
            ("-123456.", -123456),
            ("1.23e+13", 12345678901234),
            ("123.4567", 123.4567),
            ("123.4568", 123.45678),
            ("1.234568", 1.2345678),
            ("0.123457", 0.12345678),
            ("   1234.", 1234),
            ("1.235e+7", 12345678),
            ("-1.23e+6", -1234567),
        )

        max_char = 8
        max_number = int("9" * (max_char - 1))  # 9,999,999
        min_number = -int("9" * (max_char - 2))  # -999,999
        for expected, given in test:
            # for small numbers
            # if -999,999 < given < 9,999,999:
            if min_number < given < max_number:

                # output = f"{given:7}"
                output = f"{given:{max_char - 1}}"

                # converting ints to floats without adding zero
                if '.' not in output:
                    output += '.'

                # floats longer than 8 will need rounding to fit max length
                elif len(output) > max_char:
                    # output = str(round(given, 7 - str(given).index(".")))
                    output = str(round(given, max_char - 1 - str(given).index(".")))

            else:
                # for exponents
                # added a loop for super large numbers or negative as "-" is another char
                # Added max(max_char, 5) to account for max length of less than 5, was having too much fun
                for n in range(max(max_char, 5) - 5, 0, -1):
                    fill = f".{n}e"
                    output = f"{given:{fill}}".replace('+0', '+')
                    # if all good stop looping
                    if len(output) == max_char:
                        break
                else:
                    raise ValueError(f"Number is too large to fit in {max_char} characters", given)

            self.assertEqual(len(output), max_char, msg=output)
            self.assertEqual(output, expected, msg=given)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```